# Distributed Virtual Machines

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-shares, vmware

I am new to the virtualization/sysadmin and was hoping someone could point me in the correct direction.

Several years ago when I was at University, we had a type of distributed virtual environment. Students could download VMware Player, paste in a URL and boot a Windows VM and then login to a network account. Further, all of the labs would boot the same VM across the network.

I have been tasked with building a Linux Lab for the university I now work at. I am looking to do the same type of setup but with Linux and open source software.

Answer (score 0):

The VMs probably were **not distributed**.  Instead they were centralized on a Vmware environment.  Vmware player, in addition to being a basic hypervisor, can also act as remote management client to VMs hosted on Vmware servers.  That URL you pasted almost certainly instructed player to act as a client, and connect to the VM running on the Vmware infrastructure.  The VM was almost certainly not running on your local computers.

Basically, to get the same effect just setup and create your VMs, on your hypervisor cluster.  Then setup permissions, and install the remote management software onto computers that will need to access the VMs.

Comment: Would you have a recommended software? I was looking at XenServer but was not sure if this would do what I  need.

Comment: No idea, *nix based hypervisors.  I  use Hyper-V for all my VMs these days.